# Saving Dataframes with Very Large Values in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark data frame, I am performing a groupBy operation to collect all values associated with a key into a list. The size of the collected values can vary enormously. In fact, I am trying to generate "documents" by concatenating the values of a composite key for postprocessing.

To illustrate, df is a dataframe with 3 string columns A, B, C.

`df.groupBy(concat($"A", lit("-"), $"B").alias("Key")).agg(collect_list($"C").alias("values"))`

Running this query to fetch a couple of rows works, which means that command is correct.

However, when I try to save the full output as a zipped CSV, or Parquet, this process fails for several reasons, including memory issues (which I tried to tweak), and Kryptoserilization.

I suspect that having some values being extremely large is the issue. 
Is there a best practice for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Although knowing exactly what error you get would help, your problem is very likely due to the fact that too much data goes to one single row. To overcome this, you can add some artificial partitionning with a random column. This way, your grouped data will be shared among several rows and then several files, preventing OOM errors from happening. Here is how you could do it:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 2)))
    .toDF("A", "B", "C")
```

What you are trying to do is this, and C may get too big.

```
df.groupBy("A", "B")
  .agg(collect_list('C))
  .show
+---+---+---------------+                                                       
|  A|  B|collect_list(C)|
+---+---+---------------+
|  1|  2|      [3, 4, 5]|
|  1|  3|            [2]|
+---+---+---------------+
```

Instead, you can add a random column R to prevent C from getting too big. The data will be split accross several values of R, reducing the possible amount of data that can go in one row. Here I used 3 possible random values for the example but a bigger value should be necessary in your case.

```
val new_df = df.withColumn("R", floor(rand()*3)).groupBy("A", "B", "R").agg(collect_list('C) as "C").show
new_df.show
+---+---+---+------+
|  A|  B|  R|     C|
+---+---+---+------+
|  1|  2|  1|   [5]|
|  1|  2|  2|[3, 4]|
|  1|  3|  1|   [2]|
+---+---+---+------+
```

Then you can write your partitionned dataframe like this.

```
new_df.write.partitionBy("A", "B", "R").parquet("...")
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works. I still have to aggregate those partitions in postprocessing. I am still wondering if there is a more graceful solution to handle (Key, Documents) in spark? The fact that I start getting memory overflow issues when combining the values isn't normal.

Comment: It depends. Spark is meant to deal with distributed documents. The fact that you get a OOM error simply means that some of your documents are too big to fit in the RAM of a single worker. What I propose allows to parallelize the treatments made on these big documents which is what spark is intended for.

Comment: Got it. Though at the end of the day I need to regroup a distributed set of documents into a single one per key. BTW, I just found out that this thread has a similar problem to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49567420/spark-requested-array-size-exceeds-vm-limit-when-writing-dataframe

Comment: Do you need that for further processing with spark or any other big data tool? In this case, a folder with several files in it will work fine. Therefore you just need to create folders and move files around.